# У меня есть двухмерный int vector 10х10 , как эго отсортировать? Мне нужно по возрастанию начало в arr[0][0], конец в arr[9][9]

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, vector, stl

```
vector<vector<int>> arr{
    {32,105,48,80,144,128,64,122,18,81},
    {66,129,113,17,94,78,90,51,104,34},
    {110,149,36,103,82,53,93,130,68,150},
    {41,19,124,61,85,159,115,57,72,101},
    {56,100,86,146,73,40,141,25,87,126},
    {151,71,94,15,125,76,54,99,39,140},
    {17,124,52,98,139,37,147,88,69,109},
    {35,128,67,30,93,123,50,138,21,97},
    {96,121,49,137,89,154,91,65,92,33}
};
```

Comment: А как вы хотите его отсортировать? Что получить?

Comment: `std::sort()`, наверное?

Comment: от min до max начало в первой строчке, конец в последней строчке

Comment: arr.sort(); не работает

Comment: Чтоб не писать собственный итератор для такого случая - просто перенесите все в одномерный вектор, отсортируйте, а потом назад... Или напишите собственный итератор :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort

#define N 10    //квадратная матрица

int comp (const void * a, const void * b) //для qsort сравнения
{
    int _a = *((int*)a);
    int _b = *((int*)b);
    if (_a > _b) return  1;
    if (_a < _b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {


    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr{
        {32,105,48,80,144,128,64,122,18,81},
        {66,129,113,17,94,78,90,51,104,34},
        {110,149,36,103,82,53,93,130,68,150},
        {41,19,124,61,85,159,115,57,72,101},
        {56,100,86,146,73,40,141,25,87,126},
        {151,71,94,15,125,76,54,99,39,140},
        {17,124,52,98,139,37,147,88,69,109},
        {35,128,67,30,93,123,50,138,21,97},
        {96,121,49,137,89,154,91,65,92,33},
        {-3, -21, 12, 45, 7, 43, 34, 89, 90, 100}   //это 10ая строка   
    };


    int *Arr2 = new int[N*N];   //выделение памяти для сортировки

    for(int i=0; i<N*N; i++){
        int x = i/N, y = i%N;
        Arr2[i] = arr[x][y];    //копируем для сортировки
    }

    qsort(Arr2, N*N, sizeof(*Arr2), comp);

    for(int i=0; i<N*N; i++){   
        int x = i/N, y = i%N;
        arr[x][y] = Arr2[i];    //переносим обратно
    }

    delete [] Arr2; //освобождаем память

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {   //выводим
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            printf("%4d", arr[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Danil https://ideone.com/yhcoiA  Но, похоже, вы хотели не это?

Comment: Мне нужно по возрастанию начало в arr[0][0], конец в arr[9][9]

Comment: @Danil, я исправил программу под вашу сортировку (https://ideone.com/W4Qtww).

Answer (score 5):

Ну вот простейший способ с перекопированием:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr{
    {32,105,48,80,144,128,64,122,18,81},
    {66,129,113,17,94,78,90,51,104,34},
    {110,149,36,103,82,53,93,130,68,150},
    {41,19,124,61,85,159,115,57,72,101},
    {56,100,86,146,73,40,141,25,87,126},
    {151,71,94,15,125,76,54,99,39,140},
    {17,124,52,98,139,37,147,88,69,109},
    {35,128,67,30,93,123,50,138,21,97},
    {96,121,49,137,89,154,91,65,92,33},
    {-3, -21, 12, 45, 7, 43, 34, 89, 90, 100}   //это 10ая строка
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = 10;
    vector<int> flat;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        flat.push_back(arr[i][j]);

    sort(flat.begin(),flat.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        copy_n(flat.begin()+i*n,n,arr[i].begin());

    for(auto a: arr)
    {
        for(auto b: a) cout << setw(4) << b << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/mgafpx

Минус - сортировка не "на месте", требует дополнительной памяти... 
Можно написать свой итератор, но достаточно морочливая это работа...